# Will a British consulate abroad assist a person who has indefinite leave to remain in the UK?

Tags: russian-citizens, uk-residents, consulates

My mother in law has indefinite leave to remain in the UK can she ask for help at a  British consulate abroad?

Comment: What kind of help does she need?

Answer (score 31):

British consulates and embassies cannot provide support for non British nationals unless they fit into categories below, even if they legally reside in the UK.

[Support for British Nationals Abroad: Summary](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/support-for-british-nationals-abroad-a-guide/support-for-british-nationals-abroad-summary) from WWW.GOV.UK

### **Who We Can Help**

> We can provide the support set out in this guide to people outside the
>   UK who are:
>
> British nationals (whether or not they normally live in the UK – see
>   page 6 of main guide)
>
> British nationals with another nationality (known as ‘dual nationals’
>   – see page 6 of main guide), although this will depend on the
>   circumstances - normally we cannot help dual nationals when they are
>   in the country of their other nationality
>
> Nationals of European Union Member States without a local embassy or
>   consulate
>
> Nationals of other Commonwealth countries where there is not a local
>   embassy, but only in certain circumstances (see page 6 of main guide)
>
> **We cannot provide this support to other countries’ nationals, even if they have been living legally in the UK**

Comment: As the question is tagged "russian-citizens", the asker's mother in law is probably russian, i.e. neither a national of a EU member state or a commonwealth country. And as the question talks about "Indefinite leave to remain", I'm guessing she is not a british national either, so she doesn't fall in any of those categories, i.e. the short answer to the question is: no.

Comment: @Henrik it does depend a bit on what kind of "help" she needs.  Consulates typically provide certain services to foreigners, most notably visa services, which she would need if her UK documents are lost or stolen.

Comment: @Henrik there's the off chance the woman has dual nationalities as well. Unlikely but can't be ruled out.

Comment: It's also possible that, regardless of what's written in this guide, they could still be of some assistance in a natural disaster, evacuation situation, or other extreme emergency (see the "Crisis response" portion of the document), particularly if your own country does not have a diplomatic presence there.